# WordPress - 404 for archive page of custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

We did create a custom post type called `service` and a custom taxonomy called `service_category`.
So we are trying to create the following structure;

Archive page of custom taxonomy = `archive-service_category.php` with url `/onze-producten-en-diensten` 
Taxonomy page of custom taxonomy = `taxonomy-service_category.php` with url `/onze-producten-en-diensten/{taxonomy_name}`
Single page of custom post type = `single-service.php` with url `/onze-producten-en-diensten/{taxonomy_name}/{single_post_name}`

The taxonomy and single page are working, but the archive page of the custom taxonomy returns a 404 error.

This is the code we are using;

```
/**
 * Service custom post type
 */

add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('service', [
        'label' => __('Diensten', 'txtdomain'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'revisions', 'comments'],
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'dienst'],
        'taxonomies' => ['service_category'],
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'onze-producten-en-diensten/%service_category%', 'with_front' => false), 
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => __('Dienst', 'txtdomain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Nieuwe dienst toevoegen', 'txtdomain'),
            'new_item' => __('Nieuwe dienst', 'txtdomain'),
            'view_item' => __('Dienst bekijken', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found' => __('Geen dienst gevonden', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Geen dienst gevonden in de prullenbak', 'txtdomain'),
            'all_items' => __('Alle diensten', 'txtdomain'),
            'insert_into_item' => __('Dienst toevoegen', 'txtdomain')
        ],      
    ]);
});

/**
 * Service taxonomy
 */

add_action('init', function() {
    register_taxonomy('service_category', ['service'], [
        'label' => __('Dienst categorieen', 'txtdomain'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'onze-producten-en-diensten'),
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => __('Dienst categorieen', 'txtdomain'),
            'all_items' => __('Alle dienst categorieen', 'txtdomain'),
            'edit_item' => __('Dienst categorie bewerken', 'txtdomain'),
            'view_item' => __('Dienst categorie bekijken', 'txtdomain'),
            'update_item' => __('Dienst categorie bijwerken', 'txtdomain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Nieuwe dienst categorie toevoegen', 'txtdomain'),
            'new_item_name' => __('Nieuwe dienst categorie', 'txtdomain'),
            'search_items' => __('Dienst categorie zoeken', 'txtdomain'),
            'popular_items' => __('Populaire dienst categorieen', 'txtdomain'),
            'not_found' => __('Geen dienst categorie gevonden', 'txtdomain'),
        ]
    ]);
});

register_taxonomy_for_object_type('service_category', 'service');
```

We did try refreshing permalinks, but still no success.
Does someone know why the archive page of the custom taxonomy returns a 404?

Thanks for your time!